# Why isn't my Participle parser detecting anything?

Tags: parsing, go

I am writing a parser / lexer using Participle (a package for Golang) for use in a game. It's supposed to look like Bash commands, but be easier. (https://github.com/alecthomas/participle)

Here is the code that Participle uses to lex and parse the inputs. (They get processed additionally later.)

```golang
type Parsed struct {
    Pos lexer.Position

    FirstBlock Block             ` @@ `
    Blocks     []*BlockWithDelim ` @@* `
}

type Block struct {
    Command   string     ` @Command `
    Flags     []*ArgFlag ` @@* `
    Arguments []string   ` @Argument* `
}

type BlockWithDelim struct {
    Delimiter string ` @(";" | "|" | "\n" ) `
    Block     Block  ` @@ `
}

type ArgFlag struct {
    Flag  string  ` "-" "-"? @Flag `
    Value *string ` ("=" @Argument)? `
}

var omegaLexer = lexer.Must(ebnf.New(strings.ReplaceAll(`
    Command = alpha {alpha} .
    Flag = Ident .
    Argument = Ident | String | RawString .
    String = "\"" { "\u0000"…"\uffff"-"\""-"\\" | "\\" "\u0000"…"\uffff" } "\"" .
    RawString = "§" { "\u0000"…"\uffff" - "§" } "§" . 
    Ident = (alpha | "_" ) { alpha | digit | "_" } .

    Comment = "#" { "\u0000"…"\uffff" - "\n" } .
    Whitespace = " " | "\t" | "\r" .

    alpha = "a"…"z" | "A"…"Z" .
    digit = "0"…"9" .
`, "§", "`"))) //replace § with ` to make reading easier, due to no escapes allowed in raw strings

var omegaParser = participle.MustBuild(&Parsed{},
    participle.Lexer(omegaLexer),
    participle.Unquote("String", "RawString"),
    participle.Elide("Whitespace", "Comment"))
```

The problem is, it refuses to detect anything except commands with one argument which is a quoted string.

```
# This works
echo "quoted string"

# This doesn't
echo hello
# Returns this error: 
# <source>:1:6: unexpected token "hello"
```

In addition, it doesn't recognize strings put directly in the struct tags. For example:

```
help -bool
# <source>:1:6: no match found for -

execute once; then -do="thingy"
# <source>:1:13: no match found for ;
```

I cannot figure why my code wouldn't work. I've tried to copy the TOML example as much as possible.

Here's the code (with imports and package snipped): https://pastebin.com/QDLiGmnu

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *in the body of your question*, not at an external link. External links should only be supplemental to the question itself.

Comment: I think I added that... I've never really asked questions on StackOverflow before sorry

Comment: Your struct tags all look wrong - they all have leading/trailing whitespace which they should not. That may be contributing to at least some of your issues.

Comment: According to the participle docs, that should be OK...
```
type Value struct {
  String *string  `  @String`
  Number *float64 `| @Float`
}
```
note the leading space on String

Comment: Yep, that didn't work.